# Is it "it is", or is it "it's?

Tags: contractions, formality

My English teacher says to use "it is" instead of "it's" and "do not" instead of "don't" because it is more formal. For example, I can say

> I have a toy plane, and it is blue. Do not touch it.

or

> I have a toy plane, and it's blue. Don't touch it.

Is it true or not?

Comment: We're going to need more information. How are you using these words? What circumstances does your teacher say not to use contractions in?

Comment: Yes, it's true that it's more formal, but depending on the context, you should know both.

Comment: This mostly applies on writing tasks. You are required to be more formal, so contractions are seen informal. When speaking, it depends to who you are speaking and the "formal" situation.

Comment: You'll find of wealth of information on this topic if you [search online](http://www.google.com/search?q=when+to+avoid+contractions). For example, [here's a blog post](http://www.everythingenglishblog.com/?p=558) summarizing conventional thought with regard to contractions, and [here's another](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2006/04/dont_use_contra.html) that relaxes those restrictions a bit. I'd say your teacher is overemphasizing things, particularly when it comes to conversational English. Your second sentence is just fine.

Comment: where else could I post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the main reason for not using contractions is emphasis or need for clarity.  Examples include reading directions out loud, communicating serious and important facts or requests, or communicating strong warnings or cautions.  Warning signs don't tend to use contractions, for example, but this isn't consistent.

Formal social situations don't in and of themselves automatically call for not using contractions, but an educated, well-spoken individual may use them less in an effort to sound as clear as possible.

The slang contraction *ain't* is an exception and should probably be avoided in formal situations - it is definitely informal if not outright slang.

Answer (score 9):

In normal, daily conversation native speakers use contractions all the time.

In written English, contractions are avoided in formal texts.

Comment: That's totally wrong. Not all the native speakers use contractions all the time in normal, daily conversations. They don't use contractions for emphasis. It depends. Do you want me to show you how contractions are used in formal texts?

Comment: This is far from "totally wrong;" this is a terse summary of reality.

Comment: Almost all native speakers use contractions almost all the time in normal, daily conversations. But that's just my own experience having been born in the U.S. and living here for over half a century...